# jQuery hide() then animate() then show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, show-hide

Why doesnt this work

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $("#sliderWindow").find("img").each(function(i) {
    var left = $(this).css("left");
    $("#imageContainer" + i).animate({"left": "+=220px"}, "slow");
    left = parseInt(left);
    left += 220;
    left = left + "px"; 
    $(this).css("left",left);
    left = $(this).css("left");

    if(left === "1220px") {
      //this is what doesnt work
      $(this).css("left", "-320px");
    }
```

I am sliding a row of divs with animate. Once the last div gets to absolute position left:-1220px, move it back to the start position left:-320px. It is moving to the correct position but I am having trouble hiding it.

EDIT: The reason I am animating a hidden div is because the animation doesn't seem to be changing the css. Because the css isnt changing I cant roll the last objects back to the front of the line. Since I can get animate() to accomplish this I am trying to hide the last div and have it appear at the front of the line.

SOLVED:

```
$("#right").click(function() {
  $("#sliderWindow").find("img").each(function() {
     if (this.offsetLeft >= 1220) {
        $(this).css("left", "-320px");
    }
    $(this).animate({left: "+=220px"}, "slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: can you post the complete code

Comment: Why animate it when it's hidden? Kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Where's left defined? By itself it has no meaning. And what do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: really, it doesnt make any sense, you want to animate it, then show.. why dont you change the css atribute and then show it.. you dont even needs to hide it, just change the pos, it'll make the same effect

Comment: Yeah, the question doesn't make a lot of sense right now, would you use the "edit" link and clarify it?

Comment: See edit for clarification. JSfiddle is down so cant link full code. Will format for SOF in a sec.

Comment: Edited code to show JS. JSFiddle is down right now so cant link all HTML and CSS

Comment: yeah, if you can share the html as well, that would be helpful!

Comment: What your code does right now is add 220 pixels to the left position of your element.  and if that goes over 1220 it sets the left position to be -320 pixels from the left edge of your closest parent container that is either position:absolute or position:relative (assuming your element is possition:absolute) ... Are you wanting to simply move the element back 320 pixels?

Comment: @ehudokai no I am trying to move the last back to position one. I posted the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this with the following:

```
$("#right").click(function() {
$("#sliderWindow").find("img").each(function() {
  if (this.offsetLeft >= 1220) {
    $(this).css("left", "-320px");
  }
  $(this).animate({left: "+=220px"}, "slow");
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's not going to do any good to animate something after you hide it. :)

Secondly, I believe what you're looking for is animate's callback function. If you want something to happen only after the animate is complete you do it like this...

```
$(this).animate({"left": "-320px"}, "slow", function(){ do_something; });
```

Let's say `<div id="obj">` already has a "position:absolute;", and you want it to move, then disappear...

```
$('#obj').animate({"left": "-320px"}, "slow", function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

all animations all executed instantly - > you need to use jQuery

```
   delay()
```

or

```
 setTimeout(function(){},timeInMillis);
```

for example

```
if(left === "1220px") {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.hide(200).delay(200).animate({"left": "-320px"}, 300,function(){
   $this.show();
  });
}
```

Comment: but yes, as others commented it doesnt really make much sense

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the new position, since that's what it sounds like you're trying to do.

```
  if(left === "1220px") {
    $(this).css("left", "-320px");
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what Im trying to do but I tried to use the exact same code above before I came to SOF and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ...

```
if( parseInt(left) > 1219 ) {
   $(this).css("left", "-320px");
}
```

... in case it's not exactly `1220px`?